# No enum constant org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.VERSION_14

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, java-14

Using Intellij IDEA, I created a new Gradle project using Gradle 6.4 and Java 14, but when I try to build the project, I'm getting this error :

> No enum constant org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.VERSION_14

What do I do ?

**Edit 1** :
I'm using the latest EAP version of IDEA.

Comment: Same here.. started just now. No idea what suddenly is wrong with Gradle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is known issue with 2020.2 EAP version: [IDEA-243097](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-243097). Will be fixed in the next EAP update (expected next week). Sorry for the inconvenience.

As a workaround please [downgrade](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-243097#focus=streamItem-27-4189892.0-0) IDE version.

Comment: Good to see the authors pitching in quick. (y) I just reached that tracker and saw an update *"Just now"*, was wondering if I should comment there, while you've answered this. On the other hand, what is the cause behind this(in case people can look for a quick workaround)?

Comment: The cause is - the bundled with the IDE Gradle tooling library has been updated. The workaround is to downgrade.