# JDK14 on Intellij

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I use JDK14 but when I installed EAP2020.2 Build #IU-202.5428.22 I am not able to import gradle projects I get the errors below 
       `No enum constant org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.VERSION_14`

`No enum constant org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.VERSION_15`

My gradle installation is as below

### `gradle -version`

### Gradle 6.5

Build time: 2020-06-02 20:46:21 UTC 
Revision: a27f41e4ae5e8a41ab9b19f8dd6d86d7b384dad4
Kotlin: 1.3.72 
Groovy: 2.5.11 
Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.7 compiled on September 1 2019 
JVM: 14 (Oracle Corporation 14+36-1461) 
OS: Windows 10 10.0 amd64

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62345882/no-enum-constant-org-gradle-api-javaversion-version-14

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that this is a known issue on Intellij EAP as per [Youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-243097)

Which will be fixed in the next update